# "Reversed" startsWith query in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is a collection of documents and each document has a `prefix` field. Now, as an input to the query `recipient` is passed. I need to find a document that fulfills the following condition:

```
recipient.startsWith(prefix)
```

so a kind of a *reversed* (since not invoked on a field but on an input) `startsWith` query. How can I implement such query, is there any operator?

I work with a very old version of mongo: `2.6.1`.